# Integrating Data in a yaml file in Java

Tags: java, selenium, yaml

1- I want to write in yaml file value 000089 but always yaml take just 89 my yaml file I want results like :

Expected resultat:

```
codeClient:  00000068
```

2- when the value1 is in string i have result as :

```
codeClient:  '00000068'
```

3- when the value1 is in Integer:

```
codeClient:  68
```

2- i am writing with this function:

```
public  static void getTestDumpWriter(String yamlFile,String key1,String 
 value1) throws IOException { 
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
     data.put(key1, value1);
     DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
     options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
     options.setSplitLines(false);
     Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
     BufferedWriter writer = 
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yamlFile, false));
     yaml.dump(data, writer); 
     }
```

Any help plzzz!!!!

Comment: how to convert Java object string to yaml tags !!str plzz

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to parse a digit starting with zero, YAML-parser tried to manage it as octal number. But if it has digits mote than 7, it confises and result can be very unexpected.
In your case, you're operate String type, so it will be saved as '000089'. I suppose there is no other way to save a decimal number with leading zeroes and then parse it as Integer.

Comment: You haven't provided an answer to the question, but merely asked for more information. Usually it should be added as a comment instead of as an answer.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan well, it seems to be some misunderstanding because there is only "add answer" option in mobile app.

Comment: I am adding this comment from the stack overflow app on my Nokia 8 android phone. There is a provision to enter comments. But that's not what I was hinting at. I was telling you the convention that is followed in stack overflow

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Ok thanks, it will be a good lesson for me. I will rewrite this answer a little bit later, if only someone will not delete it.

Comment: now i am getting this  format String.format("%08d", id) the result: codeClient: '0000067' but i need to remove ' ' in yaml file if u have any idea? to have codeClient:  0000067 any idea ?

Comment: 0000067 without brackets means it is some number. But number can't be parsed as as number with leading zeroes. How do you want to keep a number with zeroes? Which Java type do you want to use for that?
You can't parse it that way before you don't have a type that can keep numbers with leading zeroes.

Comment: I suppose you can write your own writer or remove brackets after writing.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `value1` is a String, so I suppose you are calling the `getTestDumpWriter` function like this:

```
int id = 68;
getTestDumpWriter(yamlFile, "codeClient", Integer.toString(id));
```

And the integer 68 is converted to the string "68". You need to format it right away, because Yaml won't do that for you.

```
int id = 68;
getTestDumpWriter(yamlFile, "codeClient", String.format("%08d", id));
```

Comment: I am Using this :getDumpWriterYaml(SecondyamlFilePath,"codeClient","0000067"); and i want  0000067 in yaml file and  not 67

Comment: i can get now  with this format the result: codeClient: '0000067'  but i need to remove  ' ' in  yaml file if u have any idea?